# PHP: How to call option value in if statement?

Tags: php, database

I have this drop down list

```
    echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    echo "<option value='all'>All</option>";
    foreach ($dbo->query($quer) as $noticia) {
    echo "<option value='$noticia[id]'>$noticia[sub_category]</option>";
    }
```

What i want is to have 2 options, is to show "all" or one specific sub category from database
Here is my current code:

```
   if($_POST['subcat'] == $subcat) {
   $query = "Select ... where subcat = '".$subcat."'" }
   else{
   $query = show all;
```

My problem is that when I choose the dropdown value ALL, is doesn't go to else but still in the $subcat. How do I call

```
    <option value='$noticia[id]'>
```

I try:

```
   if($_POST['subcat'] == $noticia[id]
```

but not working..

Answer (score 1):

Break your query up, depending on the value of `$_POST['subcat']`

```
$query = "Select ... ";
if($_POST['subcat'] != 'all') {
    $query .= " where subcat = '".$subcat."'";
}
$query .= "...";
```

Comment: Good, can also add `&& !empty($_POST['subcat'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['subcat'] == 'all') {
   $query = show all;
   else{
   $query = "Select ... where subcat = '".$subcat."'" }
}
```